# Find the id of the html input type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a page like

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddBusinessUnit" value="Add Business Unit" class="clsAddBusinessUnit" alt="testBtn" />
```

On its click event, I want to display the id 'btnAddBusinessUnit' in alert messege.
Kindly help. I am completely new to javascript and jquery.

```
$(".btnAddBusinessUnit").button().on("click", function (event) {
                        var _Id = $(this).attr('id');
                        alert(_Id .html());
                    })
```

Comment: Simple `alert(this.id);`

Comment: @Satpal one more thing. What if I want to display the alt text on alert?

Comment: Use `alert($(this).attr('alt'));` However I would recomend you to use `data-*`custom attribute then you can use `alert($(this).data('alt'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.clsAddBusinessUnit').click(function(){
  var id= $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

OR

```
 $('#btnAddBusinessUnit').click(function(){
      var id= $(this).attr('id');
      alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
$("#btnAddBusinessUnit").on("click", function (event) {
   alert(this.id);
})
```

or

```
$(".clsAddBusinessUnit").on("click", function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".clsAddBusinessUnit").on("click", function(event) {
        alert(this.id);
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnAddBusinessUnit" value="Add Business Unit" class="clsAddBusinessUnit" />
```

Comment: I think you wanted a `#` not a `.` to get by id rather than class…